# Given the pH optimum of Angiotensin 1, how do I determine its charge?

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

I'm given the following information
[image]

I'm then asked to determine the charge of the substrate Angiotensin 1 at the pH-optimum. I have found the pH-optimum to be 6.9.

How do I go about answering this question only knowing the optimum pH and the protein chain that Angiotensin 1 is composed of?

Comment: The only charged groups are the N-terminus, the C-terminus and the arginine side chain. Depending on conditions, there is a slight chance for the histitidine side chains to be charged as well.